# Receiving an error saying nested schema in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    created: new Date()
})

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

After adding new Date() I get an error saying : 
TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `created`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that your intention was to have a `Date` field type with a mongoose `default` value of the current date time ... since you named that field `created`. I would go a step further and name it `created_At` ...

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    created_At: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

Now you will have an auto filled `created_At` Date field every time you create a new `user` model.

We specifically said what type we want the field to be and we also added a `default` value.

You can read more about [mongoose defaults here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html)

Comment: app.put('/users/:id', (req,res) => {
    Users.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {
        $set:{
            name: req.body.name,
            created_At: req.params.created_At
        },
        function(err, result){
            if(err){
                res.json(err)
            }else{
                res.json({'result': 'ok'})
            }
        }
    })
})

I tried updating it like but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you get an error or? What is the value of `req.params.created_At`?

Answer (score 3):

You are defining schema and you just need a type there not the object. Instead of using `new Date()` just use `Date`.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    created: Date
})

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```